# Set variable if not defined

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can I set a local variable if it is not defined or is nil?
Have tried this without success:

```
2.1.1 :001 > defined? a
 => nil 
2.1.1 :002 > if defined? a == nil
2.1.1 :003?>   a = 100 
2.1.1 :004?>   end
 => nil 
2.1.1 :005 > a
 => nil
```

Comment: should be `unless defined?(a)`

Comment: `2.1.1 :017 > if defined?(i)
2.1.1 :018?>   i=500
2.1.1 :019?>   end
 => nil 
2.1.1 :020 > i
 => nil `

Comment: What about `if a.present?` or `unless defined? a a = 100 end`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do the following, beware of `false` values though

```
a ||= 100
```